# How does WolframAlpha calculate the alternate forms of sin(x)?

Tags: trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

I have been searching up the sine of some angles and I noticed that WolframAlpha had some alternate forms that had division and square roots (but only for angles divisible by 3), kind of like sine of the basic angles (30 degrees, 45 degrees, 60 degrees, etc.). How does WolframAlpha calculate the alternate forms of the sine of angles divisible by 3 with square roots and division?

I tried dividing the basic angles by some value and seeing the relationships between the sine of the basic angle and the sine of the basic angle divided by the value, but I couldn't find anything. Next, I searched Google, but I couldn't find any helpful results. How does WolframAlpha calculate the alternate forms of the sine of angles divisible by 3 with square roots and division?

Here are some pictures:

[An exact form of sin(15).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkNCd.png)

[An alternate form of sin(111).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI7jj.png)

Comment: This blog post may be of interest: https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/how-do-you-find-exact-values-for-the-sine-of-all-angles-6212

Comment: @player3236 Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I have no idea on how Wolfram does these. However, you can expand $\sin(60-45)$ for the first one and expand $\sin(66+45)$ for the second one. The above link provided by player3236 shows how to calculate the trig values for multiples of 3 (to find, for example $\sin(66)$).